# How to manually set a line number for end statement in algorithm2e?

Tags: algorithm2e, line-numbering

I can manually set line numbers in an algorithm2e environment using the `\nlset` command (together with `\LinesNotNumbered`). However, I can't figure out how to make the same for lines with the `end` or `else` statements, as in the following picture:

[image: Example algorithm2e output]

Comment: If this question is still open, can you provide a compilable example ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using

- A special `if-then-else` construct called `\nlIf`
- A wrapper macro `\nlsetend` redefining locally this `\nlIf` (to be called before it), to add the custom line number

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{algorithm2e,amsmath} 

\newcommand{\nlsetend}[1]{%
\SetKwIF{nlIf}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{then}{else if}{else}{\nlset{#1}end}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \eIf{$\hdots$}{
        \eIf{$rank \neq \hdots$}{
            send\;
            send\;
        }{
            $\hdots$
        }
    }{
        $\hdots$\;
    }
    \eIf{$\hdots$}{
        \nlsetend{test}
        \enlIf{$rank \neq \hdots$}{
            send\;
            send\;
            }{
                $\hdots$
                }
                }{
                    $\hdots$\;
    }

\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]